# mysql query taking longer than expected

Tags: mysql

Here is my query to compare two tables and get the data of people which were not present in the other table

```
SELECT 
    id,
    registrationnumber,
    CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) name,
    admissionclass,
    section
FROM
    studentsdata
WHERE
    registrationnumber NOT IN (SELECT 
            reg_number
        FROM
            attendance);
```

But this query is taking nearly 1 minute to execute as we have some 8000 people data and for each row it should check with the other table data.

Do I have any alternative for this?

Edited:
Comment from BRvaja worked and after creating index it loads data quickly

```
create index reg_number_index on attendance (reg_number);

create index registrationumber_index on studentsdata (registrationnumber);
```

Comment: add indexes for registrationnumber,reg_number

Comment: As a minimum, questions about query performance ALWAYS require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables as well as the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: Please use MySQL procedure, it will be very quick. Apply same logic in procedure.

Comment: Ok @Strawberry let me edit the code.

Comment: I used that too @RaghbendraNayak . Its taking nearly 40 secs.

Comment: What is your expectations?

Comment: Thanks @BRjava it worked and now it takes only 0.078 seconds to load the data

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    id,
    registrationnumber,
    CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) name,
    admissionclass,
    section
FROM
    studentsdata
        LEFT JOIN
    attendance ON studentsdata.registrationnumber = attendance.reg_number
WHERE
    attendance.reg_number IS NULL
```

Comment: This is taking more time than my query

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT 
    st.id,
    st.registrationnumber,
    CONCAT(st.name, ' ', st.surname) name,
    st.admissionclass,
    st.section
FROM
    studentsdata as st
        INNER JOIN
    attendance as at ON st.registrationnumber != at.reg_number
```